# Invalid AST Node with GQL query that works in playground

Tags: python, python-3.x, gql, gqlquery

I can get this exact query to execute and return data in the GQL playground.
During debug, I can capture the query string immediately prior to passing it to gql.

I will not be able to share the schema

The query is

```
query {
      vessels{
        vessel {
          mmsi
          imo
          name
          shipType
         }
    }
 }
```

The error

```
Invalid AST Node: '\n    query {\n          vessels{\n            vessel {\n              mmsi\n              imo\n              name\n              shipType\n             }\n        }\n     }\n\n    '
```

I've tried all sorts of debugging to figure out how to fix this, but no go

Answer (score 6):

The error likely indicates that the query wasn't wrapped into `gql`

```py
from gql import gql

query = gql(
    """
    query {
      vessels{
        vessel {
          mmsi
          imo
          name
          shipType
         }
      }
    }
"""
)
```